# What HTTP headers will tell browsers not to restore sessions at a page resulting from a POST?

Tags: http, web, browser-cache, cache-control

On our website, we have a form that users visit using a GET request which includes some URL parameters.  Users POST the form submission to the same URL (minus the URL parameters) for a confirmation page, and then close their browsers (especially on iPhones).

The next time users open their browsers, they return to the page that they posted the form to... which is basically a GET request minus the required form parameters. So this returns an error page.

We're able to reproduce this error on iPhones, as well as desktop browsers like Firefox but restoring previous sessions.

What HTTP headers can we send that tell web browsers not to return to the confirmation page URL?

Comment: You need Post-Redirect-Get

Comment: @artbristol The confirmation page is dynamic, so that pattern isn't applicable.

Answer (score 0):

If your POST is appearing in the browser's history then it could be available for navigation at a later time. You should consider using JavaScript to perform the POST and preventing the DOM's default behavior of navigating to a new page containing the POST results. Here's a small example using jQuery:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Use $.post here to post the results without causing a browser navigation
});
```

As far as I know, there are no HTTP headers that can manipulate the browser's history.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not redirect users to another page if there are no POST or GET vars using:

```
if (!isset($_POST['variableFromForm']) && !isset($_GET['variableFromUrl']){
    header('Location: anotherUrlPerhapsHomepage.php');
}
```

Bearing in mind that header must be called before any output has been sent. I.e. as close to the top of the script as possible is safest

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But I'd rather detect when the page is loaded in error and not have browsers going back to that page.

Comment: I would say your only bet is to do what Nathan said above then. If you've sent your users to that page there's never a guarantee that they won't go back unless you redirect them away.